# Does Pioneers in Database Research have enough significance to warrant a Historical Lock?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across a question from the nascent era of [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com); it was posted in August of 2011.  At that time, the details about what constituted a good question, and what did *not*, were still being ironed out.

The question asks for a list of people who have made life-changing contributions to database research.  As of the writing of this meta question, it has a score of +11, and has 8 positively scored answers.

If this question were to be asked today, it would likely be closed fairly quickly as off-topic.  See the [dont-ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section of help for the many reasons this question would likely be closed.

This is the question in, er, question: [Pioneers in Database Research](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/pioneers-in-database-research)

Should we place a Historical Lock on this question?  That would prevent it from being edited, closed or deleted, and would prevent new answers and comments from being added to the question.  [Historical Locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631) are a mechanism by which moderators can mark posts as historical artifacts. Questions which are historically locked feature the following post notice:

> Locked. This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the question is an important part of the history of [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com), and deserves to retain its rightful place in history.

Comment: I wouldn't put it that strongly, but yes, this is an obvious use of a historical lock. Just do it.

Comment: it's locked now.

Answer (score -1):

No, the question is off topic for [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com), and should be constrained to the [ash heap of history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_heap_of_history).